# Interface in SignIn with Firebase weird behavior

Tags: android, firebase, interface, callback, firebase-authentication

```
//Login class
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPassword;
    private Button mButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_login);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_login);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mProgressDialog.show();
                final String email,password;
                email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            FirebaseHandler.checkIfDriverExist(email, new DriverExistance() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSearchComplete(boolean isFound) {
                                    if(isFound)
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this,"Logged In",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Log.v("debugMood","Login is found");
                                        startActivity(new Intent(SignIn.this,MainActivity.class));
                                        SignIn.this.finish();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this,"Complete Your Profile",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Log.v("debugMood","Login is not found");
                                        startActivity(new Intent(SignIn.this,CompleteProfile.class));
                                        SignIn.this.finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this,"Failed to Login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the above code, `checkIfDriverExist` checks if it's the user's first time to log in, if it's the first time then it moves him to `CompleteProfile` activity, else it moves him to the `MainActivity`

```
//Complete profile
public class CompleteProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mName;
    private EditText mPassword;
    private EditText mPlateChars;
    private EditText mPlateNums;
    private EditText mPhoneNum;
    private Button mButton;
    private Driver mDriver;
    private FirebaseDatabase officeDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complete_profile);
        Log.v("debugMood","Complete profile bro");

        mDriver = new Driver();
        mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.driver_name_complete_profile);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_complete_profile);
        mPlateChars = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plate_chars_complete_profile);
        mPlateNums = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plate_num_complete_profile);
        mPhoneNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.driver_phone_number_complete_profile);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.complete_profile_btn);


        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDriver.setDriverEmail(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                mDriver.setDriverPassword(mPassword.getText().toString());
                mDriver.setDriverName(mName.getText().toString());
                mDriver.setPlateChars(mPlateChars.getText().toString());
                mDriver.setPlateNums(mPlateNums.getText().toString());
                Log.v("debugMood","Complete profile before database handler");
                FirebaseHandler.completeDriverProfile(mDriver, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(OfficeApp.officeApp(CompleteProfile.this))
                        ,new com.example.android.er123ambulance.callbacks.CompleteProfile() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProfileComplete() {
                        Log.v("debugMood","Complete profile after database handler");
                        Toast.makeText(CompleteProfile.this,"Profile Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The above code is the activity that the user gets redirected to when it's his first time to log in, so basically he added more data about himself to be sent to a firebase

I've added some Logcats to the code and i noticed weird behavior after running the code, below i'll post the order of the logcats as shown by Android Studio

```
//Logs order
01-29 06:33:09.775 6341-6341/com.example.android.er123ambulance V/debugMood: Login is not found
01-29 06:33:10.635 6341-6341/com.example.android.er123ambulance V/debugMood: Complete profile bro
01-29 06:33:49.445 6341-6341/com.example.android.er123ambulance V/debugMood: Complete profile before database handler
01-29 06:33:49.675 6341-6341/com.example.android.er123ambulance V/debugMood: Login is found
01-29 06:33:56.775 6341-6341/com.example.android.er123ambulance V/debugMood: Complete profile after database handler
01-29 06:37:50.775 6341-6341/com.example.android.er123ambulance V/debugMood: Login is found
```

For some reason in the `CompleteProfile` activity, the user gets redirected back to the `SignIn` activity and so it checks if it's the user's first time to login AGAIN!, the if condition will return true so the users gets move to the `MainActivity`, I'm not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it, i just didn't understand the use of different `ValueEventListeners` of the firebase..

So when i call `checkIfDriverExists()` i search for the driver using his email address through `allDrivers` node, and i used `addValueEventListener`to look for all the childs inside..

This was my mistake, because inside `CompleteProfile` activity i pass the data object to another Function which updates `allDrivers` node, so the `addValueEventListener` still listens for data change, so it returns `true` to the `DriverExistance` callback and so it goes to the `SignIn` activity and from there it goes to the `MainActivity` as the listener found that the driver `Exists`

I solved it by changing `addValueEventListener` to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` inside `checkDriverIfExist` function